# Show that $\overline{C[z]}=A(D)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=${$z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leqslant1$},

$C(D)=${$f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuos},

$A(D)=${$f\in C(D):\left.f\right|_{D^\circ}$ is analytic},

$C[z]=${polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$}.

I want to show that $\overline{C[z]}=A(D)$. That $\subseteq$ is clear ok, but how I can show $\supseteq$?

Comment: What does $\overline{C[z]}$ mean?  Closure with respect to some unstated topology?

Comment: The topology is the sup norm $\|f\|=\sup_{|z|≤1}|f(z)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean closure for the $\|f\|=\sup_{|z|\le 1} |f(z)|$ norm, right? Then use that with $f_n(z)=f((1-1/n) z)$, $\lim_n\|f-f_n\|=0$ and that the Taylor series gives a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f_n$.